# Replace spaces that are between a specific pattern with some other character

Tags: sql

For example, I have the string:

```
<Url class="class">http://www.ccc.com/Files/thumbnails/Gone Dark.jpg</Url>
```

I want to replace all spaces inside the url tag to %20

```
<Url class="class">http://www.ccc.com/Files/thumbnails/Gone%20Dark.jpg</Url>
```

Notice that the space in `<Url class="class">` remained intact while the space in `Gone Dark.jpg` have changed to `Gone%20Dark.jpg`

EDIT: The values are in an SQL database, I need to encode them in place.
the `REPLACE(path, strPtrn, strDst)` isn't powerful enough (or so I think) for this.

Comment: can you specify which rdbms are you using please?
if you are using sql server take a look to CHARINDEX : http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186323.aspx

Comment: Is this really stored as an xml fragment? Can't you do that processing before storing or just before using that url?

Comment: CHARINDEX sounds promising, but can you help me get started, I have almost zero experience in sql. And no I can't do it before because the values are already in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one without using variables
You can process all the records in the table at once

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(url,CHARINDEX('>',url))+
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(url,
                      CHARINDEX('>',url)+1,
                      CHARINDEX('</',url)-CHARINDEX('>',url)-1),
            ' ', '%20') +
    RIGHT(url,LEN(url) - CHARINDEX('</',url) + 1)
  FROM t1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/801eeb/12)

Comment: Yes, this is a better solution and it does work for all cases I tested.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the other method in the URLEncoder class: `URLEncoder.encode(String, String)`. The first parameter is the String to encode; the second is the name of the character encoding to use (e.g., "UTF-8").

or

you should try something like this

```
String url = "http://example.com/query?q=" + URLEncoder.encode("random word £500 bank $", "ISO-8859-1"); // Or "UTF-8".
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this in 1 minute, have no time to think too much about it (i'm at work), it's just to give you a hint

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/5194

```
declare @input nvarchar(max) = '<Url class="class">http://www.ccc.com/Files/thumbnails/Gone Dark.jpg</Url>'
declare @opentag nvarchar(256) = SUBSTRING(@input, 1, CHARINDEX('>', @input))
declare @closetag nvarchar(256) = SUBSTRING(@input, CHARINDEX('</',@input), 6)
declare @data nvarchar(max) = SUBSTRING(@input, CHARINDEX('>', @input)+1, LEN(@input)-LEN(@opentag)-LEN(@closetag))

select @opentag + REPLACE(@data, ' ', '%20') + @closetag
```

Comment: Thank you, it does work. I would love an explanation for why this solution, for learning purposes.

Comment: this solution is for sure not the best possible but it's the first thing I had in mind: extract the data I want to manipulate, manipulate it and re-add the tags around it. Surely there are better solutions (and more elegant too)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java then you can encode the url using `URLEncoder.encode()` method before storing the same in the database. That way, the spaces and also the special characters will be handled accordingly.

Comment: Which database are you using? And Are you storing the whole tag in the database or just the url?

Comment: Are you parsing the xml before giving it to view layer? You can implement url encoding logic between parsing and giving it to view. Can you please explain how are you fetching the xml and displaying it in the view?

Comment: The view layer is a closed box for me

Comment: So, are you fetching the whole xml from the database and giving it straight to view?

Comment: It fetches the data directly.

Comment: How this xml gets generated and stored in the database? May be you can insert the url encoding logic while creating xml.

Comment: Yes and I have done it. But I need to do something with the data.

Comment: For the existing data, while fetching it, you can do something like, finding the string between <Url class="class"> and </url> and encode the same.